# Why does Keychain ask for the same password twice?

Tags: macos, security, password, keychain

For security reasons, I have a different password on my keychain than my user account password.  I have achieved this by opening Keychain Access.app, right-clicking on the *Login* keychain, choosing *update Keyring 'Login' settings* and then changing the password and selecting *lock keyring when computer is sleeping*.

What I expect when I unlock my computer, when an app such as Mail.app tries to access the Keyring, I am prompted for the Login Keyring password.  This does occur.  But since multiple apps request the password, multiple dialog windows pop up asking for the Login Keyring password.  Even though entering the password into the first dialog window unlocks the keyring, the other dialogs cannot be dismissed until I put my password into each one.  Any idea how to get prompted for the password only once?

I am running Yosemite.

Comment: and those have been granted access in keychain access control?

Comment: @Buscar웃 I'm not sure how particular apps are granted access in Keychain Access, could you elaborate?

Comment: as you know each app like emil has a keychain entry, open it and check the access control for it, then grant it

Comment: @Buscar웃 Where does one do that?

Comment: @Nate Double-click on a keychain entry and a window opens with two tabs — the right tab is “Access Control”. But if your apps didn't have access to their items then you wouldn't be getting a dialog to unlock the keychain, you'd be getting “X wants your confidential information. Allow Always/Deny/Allow”.